# Loop one more time in For Enumerated

Tags: ios, swift

I have this code below that's looping through all the key string in `Dictionary`. All is well until I want to search string that is not on the Dictionary. When I search string that's not in the `Dictionary`, my code should have been doing one more loop then fall in to else of `if index != patternFromDatabase.count`, but it won't since the for loop is finished by the enumerated count of the `patternFromDatabase`.
How can I do for-loop one last time after enumerated is finished since I cant just write `patternFromDatabase.enumerated() + 1`.

Do you have any suggestion? or Should I modify my code a little bit so I don't have to face this problem to outcome my purpose?
Thank you very much. If you need more explanation I'll be happy to explain the code for you.

```
for (index, key) in patternFromDatabase.enumerated() {

            let startTimeForBitap = Date()

            print("i: \(index), db: \(patternFromDatabase.count), key: \(key)")

            if index != patternFromDatabase.count {

                if Algorithm().searchStringWithBitap(key, pattern: insertedPattern) == -1 {
                    continue

                } else {

                    let endTimeForBitap = Date().timeIntervalSince(startTimeForBitap)
                    bitapRunningTime.text = "\(convertTimetoMS(time: endTimeForBitap)) ms"
                    print("BITAP FOUND: \(endTimeForBitap)")

                    let bitapTextResult = pattern[key]
                    print(bitapTextResult ?? "")
                    bitapTextLabel.text = bitapTextResult
                    bitapPatternLabel.text = key
                    break
                }

            } else {

                let endTimeForBitap = Date().timeIntervalSince(startTimeForBitap)
                bitapTextLabel.text = "Pattern NOT FOUND"
                bitapPatternLabel.text = "Pattern NOT FOUND"

                bitapRunningTime.text = "\(convertTimetoMS(time: endTimeForBitap)) ms"
                print("BITAP NOT FOUND: \(endTimeForBitap)")
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I modify my code a little bit so I don't have to face this problem to outcome my purpose?

Yes. There are standard library methods to check if an array contains an
element with given properties. In your case:

```
if patternFromDatabase.contains(where: { key in Algorithm().searchStringWithBitap(key, pattern: insertedPattern) != -1 }) {
    print("found:", key)
} else {
    print("not found")
}
```

Or, if the index of the found element is relevant:

```
if let idx = patternFromDatabase.index(where: { key in Algorithm().searchStringWithBitap(key, pattern: insertedPattern) != -1 }) {
    print("found at:", idx)
} else {
    print("not found")
}
```

*References:*

> [`contains(where:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2297359-contains)
>
> Returns a Boolean value indicating whether the sequence contains an element that satisfies the given predicate.
>
> [`index(where:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1688966-index)
>
> Returns the first index in which an element of the collection satisfies the given predicate.

Comment: wow this is some high level code, Sir. 
So it means the if is still inside the for loop, right?

Comment: @chronycles: The closure `{ key in ... }` is executed for each array element in turn. It the closure returns true then the `contains(where:)` function returns, otherwise it continues with the next element.

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3.0

// asssyme haveResult is Bool for result

```
  // if you need one more loop even if he get result you can use same way


        let dict = ["c": 123, "d": 045, "a": 456]

        for (index, entry) in dict.enumerated() {

            if index ==  dict.count-1 {  // Last loop

                if  !haveResult {
                    // make external call

                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: won't it affect the last loop? because you just dismissed one loop and take that last loop for another purpose.

Comment: not affect the last loop after you do your work in last loop you can check if result found or will need another call